# Need help to inconsistency problem

Tags: symbolic-logic

I am using theThe Logic Book)
I need help to find the inconsistencies.
using SD

1.(E V F)=>(G & -I)

2.(G V F)=>I

3 -F=> E

I tried everything to show it
I think showing  -I and I might do it
But deriving it has got me stumped
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because forum is not a homework site

Comment: This is not a homework problem. I do it for fun and learning. I am bored in lockdown. l am 58 years old. @SwamiVishwananda.  Did you downvote me. If so upvote me

Comment: What is "SD"???

Comment: According to a book review (albeit of the 1st ed.), your book uses some kind of Fitch style system for proofs... which from a google search inside the book it calls SD... which is not a term anyone else uses for that FYI.

Comment: Another FYI: I suggest you read about [resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) and analytic tableau (elsewhere) as these methods have *a strategy* for finding a contradiction (or more generally, a counter-model).

Comment: Already went through that chapter. Pretty good at it. Still somewhat shaky on using SL: Sentential Logic Derivations (Chapter 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examine the premises

```
   1.|  (E V F)=>(G & -I)  Premise
   2.|  (G V F)=>I         Premise
   3.|_ -F=> E             Premise
```

By inspection, *if you could* derive `-F` then you may derive a contradiction (`I & -I`) using these premises by a straightforward argument.

Well you *can* derive `-F` at root context by negation introduction: since under an assumption of `F` the same contradiction is entailed by the same argument.

Tip: Since we have the same argument, we should avoid duplication of effort by first deriving `(E V F) => (I & -I)`.

```
   4.|  |_ E V F
     |  :
  10.|  |  I & -I
  11.|  E V F => (I & -I)
```

Once you have filled in that argument, you can complete the proof.

```
  12.|  |_ F
  13.|  |  E V F
  14.|  |  I & -I
  15.|  -F
  16.|  E
  17.|  E V F
  18.|  I & -I
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, consider ~F -> E is equivalent to (E V F).  Together with (E V F)->(G & -I), you obtain G & ~I.  Then G and G V F -> I gives you I.  So now we have I and ~I.  Formalize that as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the hint